# Redux reducer: not sure if I am setting items (new or old) to state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a website for my end term project at school.

So far I have two views I am trying to render. Both returning a collection from my express/api endpoint. One behaves sort of correctly and the other completely borks.

I believe my problem is the way I am creating new state in the reducer and knowing when a dumb component has access to props. But before we get to that, here are the errors.

On the not so borky page:

> invariant.js:42 Uncaught (in promise) Error: setState(...): takes an
>   object of state variables to update or a function which returns an
>   object of state variables.

And,

> Warning: SingleCountry.state: must be set to an object or null

On the second page:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: setState(...): takes an object of state
>   variables to update or a function which returns an object of state
>   variables.

Also I'm getting:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

This happens when I try to navigate to a single page/view from my not so borky first page. That shouldn't be happening as I believe my route is pretty much locked down.

This is from routes/api, I am using Express...

```
router
  .route('/')
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    return Country.findAll({ include: [Aircraft] })
      .then(countries => {
        countries.filter(country => {
          return country.aircrafts.length > 0;
        });
      })
      .then(countries => res.json(countries))
      .catch(next);
  })
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body) {
      Country.create(req.body)
        .then(country => {
          country.save();
          res.json(country);
        })
        .catch(next);
    }
  });
```

This is the aforementioned reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
  topFiveCountries: [],
  oneCountry: {},
  countries: [],
};

// ACTION TYPES

const GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI = 'GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI';
const GET_COUNTRY = 'GET_COUNTRY';
const GET_COUNTRIES = 'GET_COUNTRIES';

// ACTION CREATORS
export function getTopFiveCountriesByGFI(topFiveCountries) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI,
    topFiveCountries,
  };
  return action;
}

export function getCountry(country) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_COUNTRY,
    country,
  };
  return action;
}

export function getCountries(countries) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_COUNTRIES,
    countries,
  };
  return action;
}

//THUNK CREATORS

export function fetchTopFiveCountriesByGFI() {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get('/api/countries/top-five-countries')
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(countries => {
        const action = getTopFiveCountriesByGFI(countries);
        dispatch(action);
      });
  };
}

export function fetchCountry(countryId) {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get('/api/countries/' + `${countryId}`)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(country => {
        const action = getCountry(country);
        dispatch(action);
      });
  };
}
export function fetchCountries() {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get('/api/countries')
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(countries => {
        const action = getCountries(countries);
        dispatch(action);
      });
  };
}

// REDUCER
const rootReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COUNTRIES:
      return action.countries;
    // return { ...state, countries: action.countries };
    // return (state.countries = state.countries.concat(action.countries));
    case GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI:
      // return action.topFiveCountries;
      return { ...state, topFiveCountries: action.topFiveCountries };
    case GET_COUNTRY:
      return action.country;
    // return { ...state, oneCountry: action.country };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

The funny thing the way I am going about them are not too dissimilar for each other. They are both dumb components:

First the TopFiveCountriesByGFI:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function TopFiveCountriesByGFI(props) {
  const topFiveCountries = props.topFiveCountries;

  const flagStyle = {
    height: '50px',
    width: '100px',
  };
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="twelve columns">
        <h2> - Top Five Coutries By GFI -</h2>
        <table className="u-full-width">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>GFI</th>
              <th>Flag </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          {topFiveCountries.map(function(country) {
            return (
              <tbody key={country.id}>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <Link className="country-page-link" to={`/countries/${country.id}`}>
                      {country.name}
                    </Link>
                  </td>
                  <td>{country.GFI}</td>
                  <td>
                    <img style={flagStyle} src={country.flagUrl} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Second is the Countries view:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Countries(props) {
  console.log('props', props.countries);

  const countries = props.countries;
  const flagStyle = {
    height: '50px',
    width: '100px',
  };
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="twelve columns">
        <h2> - Countries -</h2>
        <table className="u-full-width">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>GFI</th>
              <th>Flag </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          {countries &&
            countries.map(function(country) {
              return (
                <tbody key={country.id}>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Link className="country-page-link" to={`/countries/${country.id}`}>
                        {country.name}
                      </Link>
                    </td>
                    <td>{country.GFI}</td>
                    <td>
                      <img style={flagStyle} src={country.flagUrl} />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              );
            })}

          {/*  {countries ? (
            countries.map(country => {
              return (
                <tbody key={country.id}>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Link className="country-page-link" to={`/countries/${country.id}`}>
                        {country.name}
                      </Link>
                    </td>
                    <td>{country.GFI}</td>
                    <td>
                      <img style={flagStyle} src={country.flagUrl} />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <div>Sorry no content yet!</div>
          )}*/}
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

**UPDATE**
As Deryck pointed out one of my endpoints wasn't returning anything but I am still getting this error:

`SingleCountry.state: must be set to an object or null`

Answer (score 3):

You return an `undefined` value inside your promise's `then`, which tries to go into `res.json(countries)` which then fails/throws.  It gets back to the page as `undefined` still, resulting in your `setState()` issue since there's nothing there.

So, inside of this block

```
return Country.findAll({ include: [Aircraft] })
  .then(countries => {
    countries.filter(country => {              // <<-------- add `return` before countries
      return country.aircrafts.length > 0;
    });
  })
  .then(countries => res.json(countries))
```

Comment: Hey thanks that seemed to get me out of one level deep of the wilderness...(MUCH appreciated).

I am still getting this error i.e. when I try to click off that first collection into a single view . `SingleCountry.state: must be set to an object or null`

Comment: I may just be kinda blind but I don't see `SingleCountry` anywhere